# simple probability equation dilemma

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let's say I have two dependent random variables $X,Y$
and I have the following conditions:
if $ Y \gt a$ then $f=P(X>a)$
if $ Y \le a$ then $f=P(X>b)$

then which formula is the right:
$$ f=P(X \gt a)P(Y \gt a)+P(X \gt b)P(Y \le a) $$
or
$$ f=P(X \gt a,Y \gt a)+P(X \gt b,Y \le a) $$
$a,b \gt 0$

Answer (score 1):

Neither formula is correct.  If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then $f$ is **also** a random variable, the way you have defined it.  That is to say, we can only assign probabilities to the outcomes of $f$, because although the outcomes of $f$ are probabilities, the choice of which outcome depends on $Y$.  Namely, $f$ is a dichotomous random variable that we can define as follows: let $\pi_a = \Pr[X > a]$, and $\pi_b = \Pr[X > b]$.  Furthermore, define $\theta = \Pr[Y > a]$.  Then $$\Pr[f = \pi_a] = \Pr[Y > a] = \theta , \quad \Pr[f = \pi_b] = \Pr[Y \le a] = 1 - \Pr[Y > a] = 1 - \theta,$$ and we can now plainly see that a location-scale transformation of $f$ $$g = \frac{f - \pi_a}{\pi_b - \pi_a} \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\theta),$$ presuming that $\pi_a \ne \pi_b$ (when they are equal, this is the only case where $f$ is not random, but this corresponds to the degenerate condition $a = b$).

Answer (score 0):

None of them. Observe that $f$ is a random variable with $f\in\{P(X>a),P(X>b)\}$ a.s..

Don't you mean to ask: what is the expectation of $f$?

In that case the first formula is correct.

We have:

$$f=P(X>a)1_{(a,\infty)}(Y)+P(X>b)1_{(-\infty,a]}(Y)$$

so that $$\mathbb Ef=P(X>a)\mathbb E1_{(a,\infty)}(Y)+P(X>b)\mathbb E1_{(-\infty,a]}(Y)=$$$$P(X>a)P(Y>a)+P(X>b)P(Y\leq a)$$